# Android: StatusBar White after setting fitsSystemWindows and toolbar having a primaryDarkColor

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar

I have been debugging this for quite sometime and cannot seem to find the solution.  My problem is that my statusbar is white even when I have my view with the xml line 
     `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`

A picture of the problem can be found below. Anyway, I have tried multiple solutions, but none have worked.  Here is the code for my toolbar.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  app:elevation="3dp"
>

   <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
      android:id="@+id/toolbar"
      style="@style/AppTheme.ActionBarStyle"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
      android:background="@color/actionbar_color"/>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Here is the code for AppTheme.ActionBarStyle

```
<style name="AppTheme.ActionBarStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/actionbar_color</item>
    <item name="popupTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light</item>
    <item name="theme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light</item>
</style>
```

Here is a picture of the problem.  What am I missing here? Also note that I did set the colors in the apptheme

```
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Set AppCompat’s color theming attrs -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <!--   darker variant for the status bar and contextual app bars -->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <!--   theme UI controls like checkboxes and text fields -->
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
</style>
```

[image]

Comment: why not use `<item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/someColor</item>` ?

Comment: Because this is not currently working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit embarrassing, but I was using a different style in my Manifest file.  That is why it wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

If your phone is pre-Lollipop then you will not be able to achieve it like this.Code you have written is correct and will show correctly on Lollipop devices.

Answer (score 0):

Adding these style settings to your `AppTheme` may work:

```
<item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
```

Note that this can work only for API-21 (Lollipop) or later.

Comment: This does not work.  I have added it to my appTheme as well as my actionbar style.